# Drupal 7 : Add Existing User Registration Fields to User Profile

Tags: drupal-7

I am building a Multi Step User Registration Form With Profile2's Multipage Group Functionality.Its working fine. But I want to add in built user registration fields such as 'Username', 'Email Address', 'Password', 'Confirm Password' into the First Step of the Multipage Group and don't want these fields stayed at the top as it is behaving by default.
I am new to the Drupal 7. I have checked settings, but couldn't get such settings. Can anyone guide me in this regard? Please help

TIA

Dushyant Joshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the post number 3 http://drupal.org/node/1426288 or post number 7 http://drupal.org/node/1068446(custom module). You should check first the drupal.org for any functionality first.

Comment: Anyways I guess you should be able to use views for that.

Comment: Thanks stefan. It helped me.BTW I searched a lot before I posted, and as I said in my question "I am new to the Drupal 7". It will be avoided with frequent use of drupal.